# Crash in coroutine

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

My function is quite straightforward,

**Main Thread**: Initializes a variable ->

**Background Thread**: Fire network request, assign the result back to the previous variable ->

**Main Thread**: Display that variable

Code below:

```
suspend fun createCity(context: Context, newCity: MutableLiveData<NewIdea>, mapBody: Map<String, String>, token: String) {
    lateinit var response: NewIdea
    try {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val map = generateRequestBody(mapBody)
            response = webservice.createIdea(tripId, map, "Bearer $token")
            getTrip(context, token)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.message)
    }
    newCity.value = response
}
```

But sometimes (it only happened 2 times actually) crashlytics reports crash for this line `newCity.value = response`

`Fatal Exception: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property response has not been initialized`

I don't really understand how that can happen.
Is this the correct way to return value from coroutine function?

thanks

Comment: You should initialize response before accessing. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849053/kotlin-uninitializedpropertyaccessexception-lateinit-property-preferences-has-n/62849192#62849192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if try block fails, it might happen that the lateinit variable isn't set at all. You should put the ui update code inside the try block as well, and handle the `Exception` separately:

*Sidenote: withContext is well-optimized to return values, so you can make use of it.*

```kotlin
suspend fun createCity(context: Context, newCity: MutableLiveData<NewIdea>, mapBody: Map<String, String>, token: String) {
    try {
        val response: NewIdea = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val map = generateRequestBody(mapBody)
           // does createIdea() first store it in var, then does getTrip(), then returns the result of createIdea() stored previously
            webservice.createIdea(tripId, map, "Bearer $token").also { getTrip(context, token) }  // ^withContext
        }
        newCity.value = response
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.message)
    }
}
```

***A quick tip (optional):*** You can wrap the UI updating code with a withContext that dispatches the work to Dispatchers.Main when not running in main thread, while if running in main do nothing:

```kotlin
withContext(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
    val response: NewIdea = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val map = generateRequestBody(mapBody)
        // does createIdea() first store it in var, then does getTrip(), then returns the result of createIdea() stored previously
        webservice.createIdea(tripId, map, "Bearer $token").also { getTrip(context, token) }  // ^withContext
    }
    newCity.value = response
}
```